# Updating the UI without leaking the context after an Android AsyncTask finishes

Tags: java, android

In the past I always did AsyncTasks as private inner classes. The tutorials I found still recommend this (see [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html), [here](http://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial), [here](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/), and [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Executing-Async-Tasks)). However, this has the potential to leak the context. Now Android Studio even warns about this and recommends making the class static.

I followed this advice. Here is my code for a sample project I made that updates the UI after a long running task finishes. Since the AsyncTask is static, I pass in a weak reference to the Activity and get the particular UI view that I need to update.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MyTask(this).execute();
    }

    private static class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private WeakReference<Context> contextReference;

        MyTask(Context context) {
            contextReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                // in the future I will do other long running tasks here,
                // like updating a database. I hope it is acceptable to
                // to use sleep for now. This was an actual project that 
                // I made and tested myself. 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            AppCompatActivity context = (AppCompatActivity) contextReference.get();
            if(context != null) {
                TextView textView = context.findViewById(R.id.textview);
                textView.setText("task finished");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Concerns**

The above code works fine, even though it is a pain to not just update an Activity member variable directly. Also, since I don't see any tutorials or the documentation showing AsyncTask working like this, I don't know if this is the pattern I should follow from now on.

Comment: In above code, why are using context instead of text view. Use text view and make it week reference.

Comment: agreed. Just pass in the TextView reference. If you set it, even though the context is shut, it will not do harm.